# Create circular buttons with UIVibrancyEffect like Lock Screen

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, uivisualeffectview, uivibrancyeffect

How can one create buttons that mimic the buttons found on the Lock Screen in iOS 8? Notice the buttons have a `UIVibrancyEffect` applied to their circular borders, and when you tap on one the button background also shows the vibrant effect - the background shines through.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried setting the opacity low and making the background white but it doesn't look the same without the `UIVibrancyEffect` applied.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/thpinviewcontroller

Comment: I was talking about how the whole screen looks (how it makes the background blurry) not the buttons.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html It's an API for just iOS 8 and up but I'm pretty sure it's what Apple uses for its translucent UI elements.

Comment: I've created a short tutorial on creating this effect using IB http://dannyshmueli.com/blog/2015/03/07/interface-builder-and-blur-with-vibrancy/

Answer (score 0):

The Beta version of Xcode 6 to work with Yosemite has some cool appearance settings which will get you the look you're after. You can simply place Visual Effects views behind your objects and choose vibrant as the appearance setting. It automatically inherits the windows behind with a semi transparent blurred effect.